# What is the command to check server time is sync with ntp in RHEL 7?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

What is the equivalent command in RHEL 7 for `ntpstat`?

```
# ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (ntp server ip) at stratum 5
time correct to within 102 ms
polling server every 512 s
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: probably `chronyc tracking`.
Long answer: `nptstat` itself.

> NTP server package is provided by default from official CentOS /RHEL 7 repositories.

In general two main packages are used in RHEL 7 to set up the client side:

- **ntp**: this is the classic package, already existing in RHEL 6, RHEL 5, etc.
  It can be installed by issuing the following command as root:

  ```
  yum install ntp         # this to install
  systemctl enable ntpd   # this to activate 
  systemctl start ntpd    # this to start
  ntpq -p                 # for info about the time synchronization process
  ntpstat                 # to have a report
  systemctl stop ntpd     # To synchronize a server you need: to stop
  ntpdate pool.ntp.org       # synchronize
  systemctl start ntpd       # and start again
  ```
- **chrony**: this is a new solution better suited for portable PC or servers with network connection problems (time synchronization is quicker). chrony is the default package in RHEL 7.

  ```
  yum install -y chrony      # to install  
  systemctl enable chronyd   # to enable  
  systemctl start chronyd    # to start  
  chronyc tracking           # To get information about the main time reference
  chronyc sources -v         # equivalent information to the ntpq
  ntpdate pool.ntp.org       # To quickly synchronize a server
  ```

**References**

- [RHEL7: How to set up the NTP service.](http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-set-ntp-service/)
- [21.11. Checking if the NTP Daemon is Installed](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-Checking_if_the_NTP_Daemon_is_Installed.html)